# flutter defining a method named '<'

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter
I'm trying to make a call to firebase to show the data inside the database but I get this error:

```
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named '<'.

return StreamBuilder<Event>{
```

This is my code;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
   home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Firebase_Test"),
    ),
    body: new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text("Boton"),
            onPressed: (){
              new MyCard();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
 );
 }
}

class MyCard extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return StreamBuilder<Event>{
      Stream:FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("1").onValue,
      Builder:(context,snapshot){
        if (!snapshot.hasData){
          return Container(child: Center(child: new Text("No data")));
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (_,int index){
            return ListTile(
              title: new Text(snapshot.data.snapshot.value.toString()),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me again I am new in this sdk I hope your help

My intent is to show the data in a list at the moment of pressing the button

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("1").onValue,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(child: Center(child: new Text("No data")));
        }
        return ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: new Text(snapshot.data.snapshot.value.toString()),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong with his/her question instead of writing 'try this'.

Comment: I have removed streambuilder type and changed `Stream` to `stream` and `Builder` to `builder`

Comment: good to know - inside of StreamBuilder we should write stream and builder property with lowercase. I am also new in flutter.